# Eclipse-like features in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, eclipse, visual-studio-2005, plugins

Eclipse-like features in Visual Studio

I really like the feature where you can double click (select) a variable and it is highlighted through out the page (Can see all the instances of it). How can I get this feature in visual studio (2005 or 2008 or other)? Is there an option or plug-in to turn this on?

I am sure there are features in Eclipse I don't use that would be useful but not obvious or built into VS. Also I am sure there are VS features that are not in Eclipse. If others want to add that to this thread that would be fine. This one feature is the one I use a lot and would really like to use on a daily basis.

Comment: Just as a side note, highlight-identifier-under-cursor-everywhere (sorry, don't know the short name for that) feature will be in VS2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking at [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html).  It gives you many different options and ways to customize Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see highlighting feature in VS2005-2008 but you can get it and many other nice features after installing ReSharper add-in.